# create new Thread for every file sent by client (sockets)

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, concurrency, semaphore

I am working on application with sockets. Client is watching specific directory and when user adds a file in there, the client is sending this file to the specific directory on the server side through sockets.
Now i have implemented semaphore to have many files being sent concurrently to the server.
And here is where my problem begins. I am using while loop and when client is trying to send some file, server is creating all threads it can. In such case 4, because of this :

```
static Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(4);
```

```
while (true) {       
    MyRunnable t1 = new MyRunnable("Name" + number++);

    Thread thread = new Thread(t1);
    thread.start();                     
}
```

This is my Thread class and what happens inside

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

        String name;

        public MyRunnable(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        private void saveFile(String path) throws IOException {

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096]; //4096 16384

            String fileName = dis.readUTF();
            int fileSize = (int) dis.readLong();

            int read = 0;
            int totalRead = 0;

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path + fileName);
            System.out.println("Name of the file " + fileName);

            while ((read = dis.read(buffer, 0, Math.min(buffer.length, fileSize))) > 0) {
                totalRead += read;
                fileSize -= read;
                System.out.println("Read" + totalRead + " bytes.");
                fos.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }

        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                semaphore.acquire();
                System.out.println(name + " : got the permit!");
                System.out.println("available Semaphore permits : "
                        + semaphore.availablePermits());

                try {
                    saveFile(pathToFiles + login + "\\");
                } finally {

                    // calling release() after a successful acquire()
                    System.out.println(name + " : releasing lock...");
                    semaphore.release();
                    System.out.println(name + " : available Semaphore permits now: "
                            + semaphore.availablePermits());

                }

            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my output when nothing even is send yet :

```
Name0 : got the permit!
Name1 : got the permit!
Name3 : got the permit!
Name2 : got the permit!
available Semaphore permits : 0
available Semaphore permits : 0
available Semaphore permits : 0
available Semaphore permits : 0
```

Here is fragment of my client code

```
public void watchDirectory(Path path) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        WatchService watchService
                = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();

        path.register(
                watchService,
                StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE
                //     StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE,
               // StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY
                );

        WatchKey key;
        while ((key = watchService.take()) != null) {
            for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                System.out.println(
                        "Event kind:" + event.kind()
                                + ". File affected: " + event.context());
                Runnable runnable = () -> {
                    System.out.println("Inside : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    File file = new File(pathToFiles + login + "\\" + event.context());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(50);
                        sendFile(file);
                    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                };
                
                System.out.println("Creating Thread...");
                Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);

                System.out.println("Starting Thread...");
                thread.start();
            }
            key.reset();
        }
    }

    public void sendFile(File file) throws IOException {

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];  //4096 16384

        // writing name
        dos.writeUTF(file.getName());
        // writing length
        dos.writeLong(file.length());

        System.out.println(file.getName() + " " + file.length());

        int count;

        while ((count = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }

    }
```

**I want to have one thread working on one file client sends. And when client sends more files i want threads to work concurently.
Is there a good way to do it ? Would be grateful for any help.**

Comment: If you're programming with a single-threaded philosophy, why bother with threads?

Comment: Maybe i wrote it incomprehensibly, but i wanted to have one thread started per one file client sends. I wanted threads to work concurently.

Comment: Well what did you expect? Your main code creates an infinite number of threads and starts them. Why didn't you think the computer would create an infinite number of threads and start them, when that's what you told it to do?

Comment: I see what it is doing. I just have no idea how to make it the way i want it to work. That is why i asked a question here. I tried to add some flags or if conditions inside the loop but it doesn't work. If you have any idea how to start one thread per file sent from the client let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to re-use a set of 4 threads, the best way is to use a fixed thread-pool executor:

```
ExecutorService threadPoolExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

threadPoolExecutor.submit( new SomeRunnable() );
```

(You can read more about this method in the
[documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-).)

In your case, you would create the ExecutorService outside your directory watcher, and then `submit()` a task to it inside your watcher code at the spot where it wakes up to do something.

For a good example of how to watch a directory in a thread of its own, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30284302/watch-directory-using-scheduled-executor-instead-of-hard-loop-in-java).  Following that example, your directory watcher class would look something like this:

```
public class DirWatcher implements Runnable {

    private final Path dir;
    private final WatchService watcher;
    private final WatchKey key;

    // thread pool for handling files in the watched directory
    ExecutorService threadPoolExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    static <T> WatchEvent<T> cast(WatchEvent<?> event) {
        return (WatchEvent<T>) event;
    }

    public DirWatcher(Path dir) throws IOException {
        this.dir = dir;
        this.watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
        this.key = dir.register(watcher, ENTRY_CREATE);
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            for (;;) {
                WatchKey key = watcher.take();

                if (this.key != key) {
                    continue;
                }

                for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                    WatchEvent<Path> ev = cast(event);
                    String fileName = dir.resolve( ev.context() ).toString();

                    // handle event
                    threadPoolExecutor.submit( new SomeTask( fileName ) );
                }

                // reset key
                if (!key.reset()) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException x) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

You can see the `ExecutorService` instance and the `submit()` call where your directory watcher responds to a new file being created, with a placeholder "SomeTask" for your Runnable which you'll call for whatever work you want to do on the file.

You'd call it like so:

```
public static void watchThatDirectory(String dirName) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    Path dir = Paths.get(dirName);
    DirWatcher watcher = new DirWatcher(dir);

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Future<?> future = executor.submit(watcher);
    executor.shutdown();
}
```

And now your directory watcher thread is running in the background, and will launch new threads (to a maximum of 4) to handle the appearance of new files in the watched directory.  Meanwhile, you can do other work in your main thread.